# News content blocks and custom Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, module, block

I need to create a little facility to create a news article to my editors by a php software. I have created a way to use a custom block and module to help the editors to include static or dynamic blocks and modules just including in the text:

**Example:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in mollis libero. Phasellus sollicitudin ligula pharetra magna egestas mattis. **{block name="ads1"}** Aenean lacinia lacinia sapien nec fermentum. **{module name="thename" class="Thelist" method="Show" parameter1="first parameter" parameter2="second parameter" parameter3="third parameter"}** Donec ligula lectus, egestas et molestie ac, tristique id mi. Donec sed scelerisque leo.

I am using two regex:

1. `$ex = preg_match_all("/{((?:module|block).*?)}/sm", $text, $matches);`
2. `preg_match_all ( '/^{module\s+|\G(name|class|method)=("[^"]+"|\'[^\']+\'|\S+)(?:\s+|(?=}$))/i', $module, $matches );`

The first one get all the items in the news article. The second one splits every block and modules in an array.

**The question:**
The second regex doesn't get all the parameters but just one! I need to get all the parameters that the editor writes in the content of the news article.

Answer (score 1):

You are not searching for them.

```
^{module\s+|\G(name|class|method|parameters)=("[^"]+"|\'[^\']+\'|\S+)(?:\s+|(?=}$))
                                          ^
```

You search for the term `parameters` followed by a `=`, but this does not exist. You named them `parameter1` and so on. So change to

```
^{module\s+|\G(name|class|method|parameter\d+)=("[^"]+"|\'[^\']+\'|\S+)(?:\s+|(?=}$))
```

should help you.

Comment: Hi Stema, thanks for your reply. I have posted a wrong regex. I have deleted the "parameters" item inside the regex. My aim is write any (key=value) after the "method" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to do it in 2 steps

1 to find  all modules

```
preg_match_all( '(.*{module(.+)}.*)Ui', $module, $matches );
```

or

```
preg_match_all( '(.*{(module|block)(.+)}.*)Ui', $module, $matches);
```

2 to find  parameters for each model/block

```
preg_match_all ( '(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=\"(.+)\")Ui', $module, $matches );
```

Comment: Hi Sukisan, you have mentioned only the modules, and how have I to get the blocks too?

Comment: You can change first pattern for both cases